# Firefox not loading plugins and previous session at start

Tags: 14.04, firefox, add-on

until 2 days ago Firefox (ubuntu 14.04) was fine and started with the previous session tabs. But now even if I didn't change anything it always starts with "Ubuntu Start Page"

I checked the setting "When Firefox starts:" -> "Show my windows and tabs from last time", so I guess this is right.

Furthermore some of my add-ons like Reddit Enhancement Suite are not loaded correctly (I have to disable-enable them in order to let them work every time I start Firefox), while others like Gmail Watcher still work.

There is some preference file that has been updated and I should change?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by resetting Firefox to its default state